What's an effective method to dynamically switch Rust features per project and have rust-analyzer recognize them?
I'm developing a Rust crate where GPU-dependent and GPU-independent parts are separated using features. By default, the GPU-related features are turned off, which leads to a poor development experience in GPU environments as rust-analyzer doesn't function correctly. I use nvim.
I'm looking for a method that meets the following requirements:

Ability to flexibly switch Rust features for each project
Ensure that rust-analyzer recognizes the switched configuration
Ability to change the default features setting at any time, depending on the development environment

Specifically, I'm considering methods such as:

Using .cargo/config.toml
Using bash scripts
Using other configuration files or tools

Ideally, I'd like a mechanism where appropriate features are automatically set when entering the project directory, and rust-analyzer recognizes them.
If there are effective methods or best practices to achieve this, please let me know. I'm particularly interested in solutions that consider both rust-analyzer configuration and Cargo configuration.
For context, in my project, when I'm in a GPU environment, I want to enable GPU features for better IDE support, but I don't want to change the default in Cargo.toml as it should remain GPU-optional for users.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

What IDE are you using?

@kmdreko I use NeoVim

Alright, not sure how to set rust-analyzer configuration in NeoVim, but you'd likely want to set the rust-analyzer.cargo.features parameter to the list of additional features. See Configuration in the rust-analyzer manual.

@kmdreko I don't think the way you presented it would allow me to set it up on a project-by-project basis, can I do that?

I don't have any NeoVim experience so someone else would have to say if its possible per-project or not. As an example, I know VS Code has project-specific settings where this would go.
